# How to compute the average event frequency over a partition in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, partition, data-partitioning

I have a BigQuery table that is essentially an event trace for a given user session. I would like to partition the data by track in the example and produce a frequency distribution of events averaged over tracks.

```
track Event Name
1     A
1     B
1     C
2     A
3     A
3     B
```

So for these data the result would be

A - 100%
B - 66%
C - 33%

Which is to say all tracks contain event A, 66% of tracks contain event B and 33% of tracks contain event C.

I'd like to do this with analytic functions in SQL and PARTITION BY but am unsure how to proceed.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of events (ie, only A,B,C)?  This would be fairly easy with CTEs and left joins, are you required to use analytic functions?

Comment: Yes the event names are enumerated (a finite set) - I don't need to use analytic functions that was just where my relative non-expertise in SQL led me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use partitioning, you can do it this way:

```
select event, 
   round( (count(track)/count(distinct event))/count(distinct event) over () * 100, 2) as perc
   from (
      select distinct
         event, 
         track
      from `yourdataset.table`
   )
group by 1
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT event, 
  ROUND(100 * COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY event) / COUNT(DISTINCT track) OVER(), 2) frequency
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question  - result is

```
Row event   frequency    
1   A       100.0    
2   B       66.67    
3   C       33.33
```